# How to use HttpClient in AWS Lambda Correctly

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dotnet-httpclient

I have a .net lambda function on AWS which is executed every 1 minute.

In the function, I have a `public static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` initialised at the top of my code before any functions, and all the subsequent API requests use this `client` (there are two API’s I call, A and B).

When I run my Lambda function it works perfectly for about an hour, but then API A warms me that I’m **Limited to 500 requests per minute** which leads me to believe that somehow I’m making more than 500 requests when I run my Lambda function after an hour of executing it without a problem.

I’ve checked and seen that the each time I run the lambda function after the first time, the `HttpClient client` is already initialised from the first instance of Lambda, which leads me to believe that every subsequent Lambda function after the first instance is a warm start.

So my question is: what is the correct way of implementing `HttpClient` to run every 1 minute on AWS Lambda without somehow making hundreds of requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was using everything correctly.

We have another service which also uses the same API and sends lots of API requests between specific times (It is inefficient, I know), and this was what was causing the error I mentioned in the original post.

Solution for now is to run my programme at the times when the other software is not calling the API.

Comment: Regarding "Apparently I was using everything correctly" do you have an article you can share that led you to that conclusion?  Thanks.